# "ich bin deine, du bist meine"

Tags: gender, history, poetry

I have been listening to Bach’s secular cantata BWV 213 (“Hercules at the crossroad”) to a text by Picander.. Towards the end there is a duet between Hercules (scored for a boy alto) and the personified “Tugend” (sung by a tenor), where the two repeatedly sing “ich bin deine, du bist meine”. In modern German I would expect “ich bin dein, ich bin deiner, ich bin dein(e)s”, but not „deine“, at least not here, where both parties are male. I am assuming that this is the construction mentioned, and condemned, by Grimm & Grimm & al., s.v. “dein”:

> unerträglich ist hier auch die schwache form, die man zuweilen hört
> und die STEINBACH 1, 259 gelten läszt, der topf ist deine, das buch
> ist deine.

I wonder if anyone talks like this.

Comment: I can't clearly answer this, but my hunch would be that it has to do with Picander's and Bach's saxonian provenance. See e.g. http://www.sg-döllingen.de/doellinger-mundart/: "Das ist meine – das gehört mir". Maybe someone who knows more sächsisch than me can say something about this.

Comment: @HalvarF. Danke, das ist sehr wahrscheinlich.

Comment: @HalvarF: Wow, diese Ausdrucksweise existiert tatsächlich regional? Ob das wohl auch die Erklärung wäre für die Textzeile aus "Das ist alles nur geklaut", die mich seit Jahren "umtreibt", weil sie für mich immer klang wie "Das ist alles gar nicht meine"? Wann immer ich das Lied hörte, fragte ich mich, ob das 's' von "gar nicht meines" da verschluckt wurde.

Answer (score 1):

Der Spruch *»Ich bin dein, du bist mein«* ergäbe nur Sinn, wenn Herkules und die Tugend ein Liebespaar wären, aber das sind sie nicht. Die beiden versprechen einander nicht, dem jeweils anderem zu gehören. Stattdessen verspricht Herkules der Tugend ihrem Pfad zu folgen.

In dieser Kantate muss sich Herkules zwischen zwei Gefühlen entscheiden: Soll er dem lockenden Ruf der Wollust folgen, die ihn auffordert, alle Schranken zu vergessen? Oder soll er der Tugend folgen, die ihn mahnt, auf dem rechten Weg zu bleiben.

Im **9. Satz** der Kantate (Titel: Ich will dich nicht hören, ich will dich nicht wissen) sagt sich Herkules von der Wollust los. (Textzeile aus diesem Satz: *»Verworfene Wollust, ich kenne dich nicht.«*)

Der **10. Satz** (Titel: Geliebte Tugend, du allein) ist ein Rezitativ (ein barocker Sprechgesang). Rezitative sind üblicherweise Sologesänge. Dieses Rezitativ ist aber ein seltenes Beispiel für ein Duett-Rezitativ. In diesem Satz erklärt Herkules die Tugend zu seiner Leiterin. (Textzeile: *»Geliebte Tugend, du allein sollst meine Leiterin beständig sein«*) und die Tugend verspricht ihm, sich mit ihm zu verbünden. Die Tugend singt zwar davon, sich mit Herkules zu vermählen, aber als allegorische Verkörperung der Tugend ist es ihr nicht möglich, in dieses Bündnis anders einzugehen als sittsam und tugendhaft.

Das wusste auch das Publikum der damaligen Zeit sehr genau. Diese Vermählung ist daher ähnlich zu bewerten wie die symbolische Vermählung einer Nonne mit Jesus wenn sie beim Eintritt in ein Kloster das Keuschheitsgelübde ablegt. Der Satz endet mit der Textzeile *»Wer will ein solches Bündnis trennen«*, welche Herkules und die Tugend gemeinsam singen.

Interessant ist nun der **11. Satz** (Titel: Ich bin deine, du bist meine), der immerhin fast 8 Minuten dauert und somit der zweitlängste Satz der Kantate ist.

Formal, also als Teil der gesamten Geschichte, besiegeln die Tugend und Herkules darin das eben geschlossene Bündnis. Die Tugend singt *»Ich bin deine«* und damit ist gemeint *»Ich bin deine Tugend und deine Leiterin«* und Herkules antwortet *»Du bist meine«* und bestätigt damit, dass der die Tugend als seine Leiterin ansieht.

Aber, wie in fast allen weltlichen Musikstücken dieser Zeit gibt es eine zweite, "inoffizielle" Erzähl-Ebene, die aber vom Publikum der damaligen Zeit ebenso klar und deutlich verstanden wurde wie die "offizielle" Lesart. Der tänzerische 3/8-Takt und die oft wiederholte Zeile *»ich küsse dich«* gaben dem damaligen Publikum zu verstehen, dass die Tugend möglicherweise doch eine Wesen aus Fleisch und Blut sein könnte.

Verstärkt wird das dadurch, dass die an und für sich weibliche Tugend von einer Männerstimme (Tenor) gesungen wird, und der heldenhafte Herkules von einer Frauenstimme (Alt). Es findet also ein Tausch der Geschlechterrollen statt, und in dieser Arie singen Tugend und Herkules auch immer wieder Textstellen, die in der offiziellen Geschichte eigentlich aus dem Munde der jeweils anderen Figur stammen müsste. Die Tugend und Herkules sind also beide zugleich männlich und weiblich, was auf der ersten, offiziellen Erzählebene deren Keuschheit und Reinheit unterstreichen soll, auf der zweiten, darunterliegenden Ebene, aber genau das Gegenteil bewirkt und als Vereinigung der Geschlechter interpretiert werden konnte.

Hätte Bach nun den beiden Figuren auch noch den Text *»Ich bin dein, du bist mein«* in den Mund gelegt, wäre es aus gewesen mit der Möglichkeit, diesen Satz überhaupt noch als sittsamen und tugendhaften Teil der offiziellen Erzählung interpretieren zu können. Also ließ Bach den Text so, wie er ihn von seinem Freund Christian Friedrich Henrici erhalten hatte, wobei heute nicht ganz klar ist, wie stark Bach auf die Texte von Henrici Einfluss genommen hat.

---

Noch mehr Kontext (nicht mehr Teil der eigentlichen Antwort):

Diese Kantate besteht aus diesen 13 Sätzen. (Ein Satz eines klassischen Musikstücks ist vergleichbar mit einem Song auf einer CD). Vor dem Doppelpunkt steht, wer den Satz singt, danach (hier fett hervorgehoben) steht der Titel des Satzes. Ich habe in Klammern auch noch die jeweilige Aufführungsdauer angegeben:

1. Chor (Ratschluss der Götter): **Laßt uns sorgen, lasst uns wachen** *(6:45)*
2. Rezitativ (Alt = Herkules): **Und wo? Wo ist die rechte Bahn** *(0:45)*
3. Arie (Sopran = Wollust): **Schlafe, mein Liebster, und pflege der Ruh** *(9:15)*
4. Rezitativ (Sopran = Wollust, Tenor = Tugend): **Auf! folge meiner Bahn** *(1:15)*
5. Arie (Alt = Herkules): **Treues Echo dieser Orten** *(5:15)*
6. Rezitativ (Tenor = Tugend): **Mein hoffnungsvoller Held** *(1:00)*
7. Arie (Tenor = Tugend): **Auf meinen Flügeln sollst du schweben** *(4:45)*
8. Rezitativ (Tenor = Tugend): **Die weiche Wollust locket zwar** *(0:45)*
9. Arie (Alt = Herkules): **Ich will dich nicht hören, ich will dich nicht wissen** *(3:45)*
10. Rezitativ (Alt = Herkules, Tenor = Tugend): **Geliebte Tugend, du allein** *(0:45)*
11. Duett (Alt = Herkules, Tenor = Tugend): **Ich bin deine, du bist meine** *(7:45)*
12. Rezitativ (Bass = Merkur): **Schaut, Götter, dieses ist ein Bild** *(1:15)*
13. Chor (Chor der Musen, Bass = Merkur): **Lust der Völker, Lust der Deinen** *(2:45)*

Die ganze Kantate dauert ca. 45 Minuten. Das angesprochene Duett ist der 11. Satz, dieser dauert ungefähr 7 Minuten und 45 Sekunden.

Comment: Die Rolle von Herkules ist keine “Frauenstimme”. Die Rolle wurde von einem Knaben gesungen.

Comment: @fdb: Das mag vor knapp 300 Jahren so gewesen sein. (Die Kantate wurde 1733 uraufgeführt.) Aber auf YouTube gibt es mehrere Aufnahmen dieser Kantate, und in all diesen Aufführungen wurde Herkules von einer erwachsenen Frau gesungen. Es gibt in der klassischen Musik (vor allem in der Barockmusik) zwar schon seit langem den Trend, die Aufführungen musikalisch möglichst so zu gestalten, wie sie ursprünglich vorgesehen waren, aber Herkules wird heute trotzdem nicht mehr von einem Kind, sondern immer von einer erwachsenen Frau gesungen.

Comment: Hier allerdings mit Contertenor: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=JhvlsSohsj8&t=1153s

Comment: @fdb: Countertenöre sind zwar keine Frauen, insofern hast du recht, aber es sind auch keine Knaben = Kinder. Countertenöre sind erwachsene Männer, die gelernt haben, ihre Falsett-Stimme so einzusetzen, dass sie angenehm klingt. Das können nur sehr wenige Männer, aber sehr viel Frauen. Daher sind Countertenöre selten und daher teuer, im Gegensatz zu Altistinnen und Sopranistinnen die vergleichsweise leicht zu finden und daher billiger sind. Der Einsatz von Kindern auf der Bühne geht auch deswegen immer mehr zurück, weil es immer mehr Menschen gibt, die das als Kinderarbeit kritisieren.

Comment: Der Text der Kantate ist hier zu finden: https://webdocs.cs.ualberta.ca/~wfb/cantatas/213.html und bestätigt, was @HubertSchölnast schreibt. "Deine" und "meine" beziehen sich hier beide schlicht und einfach auf die Figur der Tugend, die im Text klar weiblich ist.

Comment: @HubertSchölnast Anmerkung: Der Link mit dem Volltext von HalvarF würde sich in der Antwort gut machen. --- zur Antwort: "dein&mein" nur für Vermählungen von Liebespaaren, aber nicht für Nonne/Jesus-Vermählungen? Gibt es Belege/Erklärungen zu dieser Behauptung? Würde eine Nonne 'Ich bin deine, du bist unser' sagen, oder wie ist das gedacht?