# "Das ist alles gar nicht meine" - warum denn "meine"?

Tags: word-usage, dialect, regional

Aus einem [Text](https://genius.com/Die-prinzen-alles-nur-geklaut-lyrics) der Band "Die Prinzen":

> Denn das ist alles nur geklaut
> Das ist alles gar nicht **meine**
> Das ist alles nur geklaut
> Doch das weiß ich nur ganz alleine

Warum "meine" und nicht "meins" oder "meines"? Nur wegen des Reims? Ist das eine regionale Besonderheit?

Die Frage kam [hier](https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/72649/ich-bin-deine-du-bist-meine) auf, aber da war der Hintergrund letztlich ein anderer, und ich hatte [diese Quelle](http://www.sg-d%C3%B6llingen.de/doellinger-mundart/) zur Döllinger Mundart gefunden, die aber alles andere als eindeutig ist in Bezug auf die Verwendung:

> Mit den besitzanzeigenden Fürwörtern mein, dein, unser, euer, ihr kommen manche Freiheiten und Willkürlichkeiten vor:
>
> - Das ist meine – das gehört mir, das ist unser – das gehört uns. usw

Kennt jemand diese Verwendung von "meine" anstelle von "meins"? Oder gar eine klarere Quelle dazu?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ich stamme, wie die Prinzen, aus Leipzig. Ich kenne diese Verwendungsweise auch aus anderen Zusammenhängen. Man kann etwa Sätze wie *Wem seine isn das?* ("Wem gehört das?") sagen, unabhängig vom Genus des bezeichneten Gegenstands. Ich denke, das ist einfach Standard-Sächsisch.

Worauf das Phänomen fußt, kann ich leider nicht sagen.

Comment: Danke dir, genau so eine Bestätigung aus erster Hand war das Einzige, was ich wollte.

Answer (score 0):

***Meine*** soll sich auf ***alleine*** reimen. In Popmusik-Texten gibt es viele merkwürdige Dinge, die man nicht nach 'Sprachüblichkeit' beurteilen kann, die ist in Lyrik generell eingeschränkt und in heutiger Popmusik mehr oder weniger aufgehoben.